# drupal adding onchange event to node form

Tags: drupal, forms

hi i need to know how to add attribute onchange to a custom content_type field?

For ex my content_type has 2 fields phone (name:field_phone[0][value], id:edit-field-phone-0-value),email (name:field_email[0][value], id:edit-field-email-0-value). i'm unable to add attribute as follows.

```
 function knpevents_form_event_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) { 

   $form['title']['#attributes'] = array('onchange' => "return titlevalidate(0)");//fine
   $form['field_phone[0][value]']['#attributes']= array('onchange' => "return phonevalidate(0)"); //error
   $form['field_emai[0][value]']['#attributes']= array('onchange' => "return emailvalidate(0)"); //error
 }
```

how to add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altering the forms with CCK widgets requires a bit more tweaking as mentioned on [this Book page](http://drupal.org/node/726282). Since during `hook_form_alter`, the CCK fields are not yet processed.

Your code should probably look like (I'm not sure if the `emai` was intentional spelling):

```
function knpevents_form_event_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) { 
  $form['title']['#attributes'] = array(
      'onchange' => "return titlevalidate(0)"
      );
  $form['#after_build'][] = 'knpevents_form_event_node_form_cck_alter';
}

function knpevents_form_event_node_form_cck_alter($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['field_phone'][0]['value']['#attributes'] = array(
      'onchange' => "return phonevalidate(0)"
      );
  $form['field_emai'][0]['value']['#attributes'] = array(
      'onchange' => "return emailvalidate(0)"
      );
  return $form;
}
```

Also, I don't think you need to put the `return` there. `titlevalidate(0);` should do just fine.